# A Finite Capacity Queueing System with $N=3$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, queueing-theory, birth-death-process

The following is a question from Pinksy and Karlin's An Introduction to Stochastic Modelling:

> The problem is to model a queueing system having finite capacity. We assume
>   arrivals according to a Poisson process of rate λ, with independent exponentially
>   distributed service times having mean 1/µ, a single server, and a finite system
>   capacity N. By this we mean that if an arriving customer finds that there are
>   already N customers in the system, then that customer does not enter the system
>   and is lost.
>   Let X(t) be the number of customers in the system at time t. Suppose that
>   N = 3 (2 waiting, 1 being served).
>
> (a) Specify the birth and death parameters for X(t).

The answer provided was in the form of a transition matrix $Q$:

$$\begin{equation}
Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda&\lambda & 0 & 0\\
\mu & -(\lambda +\mu)7\lambda &0 & 0\\
0 & \mu & -(\lambda+\mu) & \lambda\\
0 & 0 & \mu & \mu
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

Is the solution correct, and how can I interpret the matrix $Q$ with regards to the birth and death parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries $q_{ij}$ for $i\neq j$ are the rates of the exponential transitions from $i$ to $j$, while $-q_{ii}$ is the rate of the exponential holding time at state $i$. So e.g. $q_{01}=\lambda$ is the birth (arrival) rate when the system is empty. The matrix you provided is incorrect; it should be
$$\begin{equation}
Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda&\lambda & 0 & 0\\
\mu & -(\lambda +\mu) &\lambda  & 0\\
0 & \mu & -(\lambda+\mu) & \lambda\\
0 & 0 & \mu & -\mu
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

(In the literature on continuous-time Markov chains, $Q$ is often called the rate matrix, or simply the $Q$-matrix.)

Comment: Ah thank you, that clears things up quite a bit! I was pretty much stuck on the ``wrong entry" in the solution..